# Form Data Appears to be something else in Request Payload in Angular 4 http request

Tags: javascript, angular, http, angular4-forms

I am trying to upload a file to the server so what I did was I converted my data json into formData, appended file to it and then sent to a request. The Request Payload that I see in the **requesPayload** is not JSON but is something else.

Here attached is the request payload screenshot :

Here is the **component** function code :

```
doSubmit(data){
 const fd = new FormData();
    fd.append('name','Tirthraj');
    fd.append('file',this.myFile);

    for (var key in data) {
      if (data.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        fd.append(key,data[key])
        console.log(key + " -> " + data[key]);
      }
    }

    this.myService.doUploadDataWithFile(fd).then();
}
```

Here is the **service** function :

```
 doUploadDataWithFile(data): Promise<any> {
    let headers = new Headers();
    // headers.append('Content-Type', 'multipart/form-data');
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'undefined');
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
    console.log("ADDElearning  DATA", data);
    return this.http.post("SERVER_API", data, options).toPromise();
  }
```

Here is the request payload :

```
------WebKitFormBoundary5Ga9J56YQxt16Ey4
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="name"

Tirthraj
------WebKitFormBoundary5Ga9J56YQxt16Ey4
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="524347_335264113233857_1091003137_n.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg


------WebKitFormBoundary5Ga9J56YQxt16Ey4
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="module_title"

312
------WebKitFormBoundary5Ga9J56YQxt16Ey4
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="module_synopsis"

123
------WebKitFormBoundary5Ga9J56YQxt16Ey4
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="estimated_time"

321
------WebKitFormBoundary5Ga9J56YQxt16Ey4
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="module_type"

scorm12
------WebKitFormBoundary5Ga9J56YQxt16Ey4
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="article_title"

123312
------WebKitFormBoundary5Ga9J56YQxt16Ey4
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="article_description"

321
------WebKitFormBoundary5Ga9J56YQxt16Ey4--
```

I want it to be like JSON Object and not what it is right now. Could anybody help?

Comment: The code uses `FormData`. Not certain what you are expecting other than `multipart/form-data`? What is `data`?

Comment: Data is a form of multiple fields. There is one File too along with the other input tags

Comment: To use `JSON` you will need to convert the `File` object to a `data URI`. What is the issue with using `FormData`?

Comment: I ain't sure how that works. Could you elaborate over it in Answer @guest271314

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have mentioned you want to send file along with form data the thing which you have done is absolutely right. only thing is missing is correct way to access that file in php. as you are sending form-data. it means you are sending whole form with name of that input field.

so you can access it like

```
echo $_POST['module_title'];
var_dump($_FILES['file']);
var_dump($_FILES['file1'])
$filename = $_FILES['file']['name'];
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'],'uploads/'.$filename);
```

Answer (score 1):

To post `JSON` representation of `<form>`, the `File` object needs to be converted to a `data URI`; `JSON` is a string.

```
const props = {};
const reader = new FileReader;
reader.onload = () => {
  props["file"] = reader.result;
}

for (let [key, prop] of new FormData(form)) {
  if (!prop instance of File) {
    props[key] = prop;
  } else {
    reader.readAsDataURL(prop);
  }
}

const json = JSON.stringify(props);
```

Comment: Will this work if the server side is PHP and not node?

Comment: Yes, though that has no bearing on the actual Question